# Vbscript: click on the button

Tags: vbscript

if I open console windows in Forefox and type this:

```
$(".activateSW").trigger("click")
```

This command will click the button.
But If I write a VBscript and try

```
    set gumbi = objDOC.getElementsByClassName("buttonBlue.activateSW")
    gumbi.item(0).click
```

I get the error - element is not clickable.
The element is written like this:

```
<a class="buttonBlue activateSW" data-id="1273199627" data-action="activate">Aktiviraj</a>
```

Please help.

Comment: Try `.getElementsByClassName("buttonBlue activateSW")`

Comment: What is `objDOC`? Please post the full code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's 
SET objDOC = IE.Document
It works! Thank you!

Comment: OK, what is `IE` then? Again, please edit the question, and post the full code necessary to reproduce the issue. Check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)